# Broken CSS on old https pages

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

Hi i have a question about importing a **wordpress.com** site to a new self hosting wordpress site.

After completing the website i still have the old https links in search results showing broken css pages: example here. https://the3growbags.com/author/rhamscallion/

The new website does not use an SSL certificate and adding one does not solve the problem, anyhow we don't need SSL. This is the non-SSL website example: http://the3growbags.com/

Question is why are the old https links showing these broken CSS pages instead of unsecured connection pages, and how do I remove them from search results? help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All your resources are linked using http:// URLs, which result in mixed content which is normally blocked by browsers.

Make sure your resources are loaded using https and your site will work.

For this you could use the protocol agnostic URL style: "//domain.com/path"